# is it possible add a javascript event and then an asp.net event to a control that runs at server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I want to have a button that runs at server but before posting back it should run one or more  javascript functions.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

OnClientClick="return func1();"

remember your function func1() should return bool true/ false. If it returns false then there will be no postback.

Comment: @Marky68 :) Great. If it worked UP Vote & check as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
function runSomeStuff() {
    callYourCode();
    callSomethingElse();
    __doPostBack('btnSave', "Some String To Post Back");
}
```